# Textile Go - Unclear description for adding files to a thread through HTTP API

Tags: go, http-post, backend, jsonschema, ipfs

I'm trying to upload a file through a POST request to a local Textile Cafe node (using Postman). I tried different configurations to guess the correct body insertion scheme, but I only got this error message (link below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXIa.png

I need help understanding what I need to do (especially the steps) to successfully upload a file (like if I need to somehow transform the input file).

Comment: Why is this tagged `jsonschema`?

Comment: @gregsdennis Because I have to use this to make a successful POST request. Please take a look at the needed schema ([pb.Directory - line 3137, pb.DirectoryList - line 3145,](https://github.com/textileio/go-textile/blob/master/api/docs/docs.go))

Comment: Please do not put (or - even worse - link) your code and error messages. If the image disappears, this question becomes nonsensical. And you make it harder for people trying to help you. Furthmore, SO is about *programming* questions, not *programmer‘s* questions. Rule of thumb: no code? Do not ask on SO.